# Opera became out of control

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, browser, opera-10

Installed 10.62 on Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit.

The first tiny problem was that I was always asked about setting opera by default, but never saved that. So I tried to write manually Opera path to the registry. Links started to open new tab in opera but without requesting a page. Also opera still asked me about default browser.

Then I set default application for `http` protocol in Opera settings. It show me that system default is the path that I set in registry, I accepted.

I just opened new tab in opera or clicked some link and tabs began opening endlessly.

I deleted opera physically. Installed 10.52 (first pack I found) and get same endless tab-opening.

Then after uninstalling Opera I cleaned registry entry that was fixed manually, installed 10.62 again - same endless tab opening.

This is something like "hello Chrome?" or there are any ways to fix it?)

Comment: Do you have a virus?

Comment: i don't think so. Tabs are empty (not adult links )) ) System installed 2 days ago. Few trusted (used before) programs installed. Security outpost + drweb + windows updates. Furthermore Chrome installed and works fine as default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed by resetting operaprefs.ini to defaults in User/AppData/Roaming/Opera